# After error 404 my stream stop working in RxJs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to learn RxJs. I have this working code but after one AJAX error, everything stopped working.

```
(function($, _) {
  var alertBox = $('.alert-box');
  alertBox.hide();
  var fetchRepoButton = $('.fetch-repo');

  var organization = $('#organization');
  var repositories = $('.repositories');

  var fetchRepoClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(fetchRepoButton, 'click');

  var requestStream = fetchRepoClickStream.map(function() {
    var theOrg = organization.val();
    return '/api/orgs/' + theOrg;
  });

  var responseStream = requestStream.flatMap(function (requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(requestUrl)).catch(function() {
      alertBox.fadeIn('fast').delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
      return Rx.Observable.Empty();
    });
  });

  var renderRepositories = function(repos) {
    // render DOM
  }

  responseStream.subscribe(function (repos) {
    renderRepositories(repos); 
  });

})($, _);
```

How do I recover from AJAX error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because you are actually terminating the stream when you return `Rx.Observable.Empty();` from the `flatMap`. You could return the error and process it downstream, instead of ending the stream.

But in the end, the answer to your question will depend on what makes sense for you (you can retry a number of times with exponential increasing delay, you can abort and continue with something else, etc.).

Generally speaking, there are a variety of operators helping with error management. This would definitely be a good starting point for going deeper in error management with Rxjs : https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html

Among the interesting operators are :

- retry/retryWhen
- catch/finally

Interesting link on the subject from SO :

- [Rx.js and application workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392730/rx-js-and-application-workflow/31393598#31393598)
- [How to build an rx poller that waits some interval AFTER the previous ajax promise resolves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856397/how-to-build-an-rx-poller-that-waits-some-interval-after-the-previous-ajax-promi/35878692#35878692) (have a look at the final answer included in the question, it makes use of `repeatWhen` and `retryWhen`)